# How to make the form to re-appear again?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am looking that if a form contains null values then the form needs to re-appear again to the user asking to fill up the information. This check has to be done in servlet.
I am trying to use the following code, but still when i click on submit button it still not happens to re-apper again.

```
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
if(request.getParameter("firstname").equals(" ") || request.getParameter("lastname").equals(""))
{
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;
}
```

Am i missing anything more?? Can somebody explain on it?

Comment: Please post the full context of your servlet here

Answer (score 0):

1. Always check for null values when ever you get params.
2. Avoid duplicate codes even if you are testing junk codes (make it a
       practice, **coding tip**)e.g. using
       request.getParameter("firstname"); in condiftion when already
       assigned to a String variable.
3. Avoid unnecessary codes. e.g "return" statement in your code

You may encounter NPE null pointer exception if not handled properly.

```
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname"); // check other condiftions as well
    if(firstname==null || "".equals(firstname) || " ".equals(firstname)){
    /* your code
    use below line to redirect to any page 
    make sure you are providing correct path of index.jsp or any servlet for redirection
    servlet mapping should be defined in web.xml*/

response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As all said,please clean up your code. And in `servlet` just do like this.

```
   if(request.getParameter("firstname") ==null){//and other conditions here
       response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");        
    }
```